# Code not working?

Tags: c++

I am learning **`C++`**. As a homework I've started to try the branching.. but I didn't quite get the hang of it... here's the code I've tried to perform (please bear patience with me if I'm making huge mistakes..)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int age;
    char * yes;
    char * no;
    bool Rated = Rated ? yes : no;
    int ticketPrice = 5;
    int discountPrice = ticketPrice - (ticketPrice * 0.1);
    int matineePrice = (ticketPrice * 0.5);
    int hour = 8 <= hour <= 24;

    cout << "Is the movie R_rated? \n";

    cin >> yes or no;

    cout << "How old are you?";
    cin >> age;

    if (age < 0 or age >100) {
        cout << "Not a valid age!";
    }
    else if ((age <= 13) and (Rated = yes)) {
        cout << "You must be accompanied by a Janitor";
    }
    else if (((age > 13) and ((Rated = yes) or (Rated = no)))
    or ((age <=13) and (Rated = yes))) {
        cout << "What time do you want the ticket for?";
        cin >> hour;
        if (hour < 8 or hour > 24) {
            cout << "Not a valid hour!";
        }
        else if (hour < 18) {
            if (age <= 5) {
                cout << "The entrance is free";
            }
            else if (age >= 55) {
                cout << "Matinee Ticket price is "<<
                matineePrice;
            }
            else if (5 < age < 55) {
                cout << "Matinee ticket price is " << matineePrice;
            }
        }
        else if (hour >= 18) {
            if (age <= 5) {
                cout << "The entrance is free";
            }
            else if (5 < age <= 55) {
                cout << "Ticket price is " << ticketPrice;
            }
            else if (age > 55) {
                cout << "You're eligibile for a 10% "
                        "discount \n";
                cout << "Ticket price is " << discountPrice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** (to which I answer **no**, **67**, and **20**) and I should get the `discountedPrice` instead of the `ticketPrice` value...

```
Is the movie R_rated? 
no
How old are you?67
What time do you want the ticket for?20
Ticket price is 5
```

Any suggestion, link or tutorial help would be really appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to the site. When posting, please make sure your code is formatted correctly; in particular, highlight it and use the `{}` button to mark it as code, as otherwise the proper formatting will be lost. But also, make sure your indentation lines up correctly, and you don't have unnecessary blank lines.

Comment: Does `cin >> yes or no;` even compile?

Comment: Can you please tell which part of the code isn't working?

Comment: (Rated = yes) returns from the assignment operator, this should be (Rated == yes)

Comment: There are so many errors in this code, its even hard to choose where to begin telling of ...

Comment: There is too much that is wrong with this code. Why don't you start with something simpler, or break the problem into smaller parts, and solve each part independently, in a way that can be easily tested.

Comment: Oh, the code compiles all right :) It's kinda fun, actually. Declarative C++ :)

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes; it's equivalent to `(cin >> yes) || no`. It should give a warning since `no` doesn't do anything and its value is ignored.

Comment: I've got your problem, you can read my answer..... and I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: @trojanfoe `or` is a keyword in c++ equivalent to `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, get rid of `yes` and `no`, which make no sense, and read the input into a string variable:

```
string Rated;
cin >> Rated;
```

then to use that, remember to use `==` not `=` for comparison:

```
if (Rated == "yes") {/*whatever*/}
```

Alternatively, use a boolean variable:

```
string yes_or_no;
cin >> yes_or_no;
bool Rated = yes_or_no == "yes";

if (Rated)  {/*whatever*/}
```

Also, this:

```
8 <= hour <= 24
```

doesn't do what you think it does. You'd need two separate comparisons:

```
8 <= hour and hour <= 24
```

although, in this case, you don't want it at all - it doesn't make sense to initialise `hour` with that. You're reading the value of `hour` and checking its range later, and don't need to initialise it here.

There are probably more problems, but that should get you started. And I hope I can still go to the cinema when I'm over 100.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code. I suggest you get a good book on C++ and learn from that. If you're already using a book, chances are that it's not good.

Here are some things, though:

`char*` is not the right thing to use for strings. You should use the `std::string` class.

Your entire code surrounding `Rated` bears little resemblance to C++.

`=` is the assignment operator. It cannot be used to compare things for equality; that's what `==` is for.

Comment: Also, can't type "or" that I know of.... although the C and C++ worlds are very strange. || works for sure, though.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner `or` and `and` are perfectly fine synonyms for `||` and `&&`, respectively. It's just that they're hardly ever used, but that doesn't make them wrong (just confusing).

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: `and`, `or` and some others are included in the Standard, in the same category as *digraphs*.

Comment: But Microsoft's compiler does not recognize them as keywords - it requires a header with macro definitions to be included. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is fixed. I've attempted to explain exactly what the code does.

```
// Declare the input/output streams, including standard streams like std::cin and std::cout.
#include <iostream>
// Declare the std::string class - it's C++, we should not use C strings!
#include <string>

// Instead of using the entire std namespace, we'll only use the things that come up often.
// This saves some typing, but is safe. Otherwise, who knows what name may clash with something
// in the vast std namespace.
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    bool ok; // Whether the most recent answer to a question is valid
    bool rated; // Whether the movie is R-rated
    int age; // Customer's age
    int hour; // Hour of the showing
    const int ticketPrice = 5;
    const int discountPrice = ticketPrice * (1.0 - 0.9);
    const int matineePrice = ticketPrice * 0.5;

    // Gather Inputs

    do {
        std::string answer; // Holds the answer to the yes/no question
        cout << "Is the movie R-rated (y/n)? ";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer.length() > 0) {
            // If the answer is not empty, we can uppercase the first letter.
            // This way we don't have to check for lowercase answers.
            answer[0] = toupper(answer[0]);
        }
        // The answer is valid when it's non-empty and when it begins with either Y/y or N/n
        ok = answer.length() > 0 and (answer[0] == 'Y' or answer [0] == 'N');
        if (not ok) {
            cout << "That's not a valid answer." << endl;
        } else {
            // The answer is valid, so we can set the rated variable.
            rated = answer[0] == 'Y';
        }
    } while (not ok); // Repeat the question while the answer is invalid

    do {
        cout << "How old are you? ";
        cin >> age;
        // The answer is valid when it's between 0 and 150, inclusive.
        ok = age >= 0 and age <= 150;
        if (not ok) {
            cout << "That's not a valid age!" << endl;
        }
    } while (not ok);

    do {
        cout << "What hour do you want the ticket for? ";
        cin >> hour;
        // The hour 0 is mapped to 24.
        if (hour == 0) hour = 24;
        // The answer is valid when it's between 8 and 24, inclusive.
        ok = hour >= 8 and hour <= 24;
        if (not ok) {
            cout << "That's not a valid hour!";
        }
    } while (not ok);

    // Output the Messages

    if (rated and age <= 13) {
        cout << "You must be accompanied by a Janitor" << endl;
    }
    if (age <= 5) {
        cout << "The entrance is free" << endl;
    }
    else if (hour < 18) {
        cout << "Matinee ticket price is " << matineePrice << endl;
    }
    else {
        if (age <= 55) {
            cout << "Ticket price is " << ticketPrice << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You're eligibile for a 10% discount." << endl;
            cout << "Ticket price is " << discountPrice << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start off with:

```
char * yes;
char * no;

// ...

cin >> yes or no;
```

makes no coding sense what-so-ever.

Comment: How do you propose to fix that?

Comment: `or` has lower precedence than `>>` so it should compile fine.

Comment: @CharlesBailey It still makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In general, "yes" and "no" are not keywords in c++. "true" and "false" are.

Alright, some things:
1) 
    cin >> yes or no;

should be:

```
cin >> Rated;
```

since variable names can't have spaces in them, as you've written it the compiler reads "cin should put something in yes, but I can't figure out what to do with 'or' and 'no'."

2)

```
else if ((age <= 13) and (Rated = yes))
```

will never work. I recommend rewriting storing the result in a string (std::string) and then setting rated according to that.

```
std::string rated_str;
cin >>rated_str;
if(rated_str == "yes") {
    rated = true;
} else {
    rated = false;
}
```

and then in the if you use:

```
if(rated)
```

or
    if(rated == true)

3) You can't reference a variable before it's fully declared:

```
bool Rated = Rated ? yes : no;
```

Comment: The compiler should be able to figure out what to do with `or no`, even if discard the result of the `or` expression is something that might raise a warning.

Comment: `bool Rated = Rated ? yes : no` is of course silly, but it compiles. In fact, the entire "bad" code compiles. The asker has probably worked very hard just to get it to compile. The code is perhaps the shining example that nonsense code can compile just fine and then be very far from working :)

Answer (score 0):

Lines:

```
bool Rated = Rated ? yes : no;
cin >> yes or no;
```

and all with

```
(Rated = yes)
(Rated = no)
```

have no sense.

First of all, if `Rated` is `bool` then you can assign to it only `true` or `false` (everything which is not `0` or `NULL` and what compiler accept would be converted to `true`).

Best quality code should use enum type for rated.

When you read, you should read to some variable and check its type.
Small fixes for you:

```
enum EnRated
{
    RRated = 0,
    NotRRated = 1
};
...
enum EnRated Rated;
string ans; //instead of yes, no
...
cin >> ans;
if(ans == "yes") Rated = RRated;
else Rated = NotRRated; //handle ans != yes or no
...
(Rated == RRated) // instead of (Rated = yes)
(Rated == NotRRated) // instead of (Rated = no)
```

Answer (score 0):

For discount ticket use:
double discountPrice = 0,9*ticketPrice;

You will input hour and test them, so you can write only:
int hour;

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

- You are doing a mistake in the following `else if` statements.
- You are not using your **`else if`** condition checker properly.
- You need not to use **`or`** keyword here... actually this is the real problem you are facing here, and you just need to replace your **`or`** with **`and`**.
- For a perfect solution please read the **Right approach** below

#### Your code

```
    else if (5 < age <= 55) {
            cout << "Ticket price is " << ticketPrice;

        }
```

---

## Right approach

This will give you your discount price

```
else if (5 < age and age < 55)
{
    cout << "Ticket price is " << ticketPrice;
}
```