# How can I rearrange this so input Ctrl-z(end of file signal) breaks loop while still testing for valid inputs in c++

Tags: c++, string, validation, parsing, io

I have two problems here.

1. When I enter a valid input(positive number) it is successfully put into the
    vector but then returns down to the next blank line waiting for another input when
    it should just ask the same question again. And it does. just only every other input
    Why is it stopping on a blank line like that?
2. How can I rearrange this so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will signal end of file instead of failing as 
    an invalid input?

   ```
   do
   {   
    cout << "\nPlease enter a homework score<'Ctrl-z' when done>: ";
    cin >> value;

    while(cin.fail() || value < ZERO)
    {
        cout << "not a valid positive numerical value. try again. \n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
        cout << "\nplease enter a valid homework score<'Ctrl-z' when done>: ";
        cin >> value;
    }  
        assignmentScore.push_back(value);

   }while(cin >> value);
   ```

Comment: i think using a sentinel value would be alot simpler here

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with debugger? That might be much more enlightening than any explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can read the input word by word and parse these words separately. If the number can not be retrieved from the word, user will be asked to enter the input again. 
If there are no more words, the loop will stop:

```
std::string word;
std::cout << "Enter score: ";
while (std::cin >> word) {
    unsigned int value;
    std::istringstream is(word);
    if (is >> value) {
        assignmentScore.push_back(value);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::endl
               << word << " is not a valid positive numerical value. try again.";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enter score: ";
}
```

just avoid using `cin.fail()` for checking whether the retrieving of input with last `>>` was successful and don't forget to `#include <sstream>` :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The reason why your question is not shown is because you ask for it twice, only once showing the question. The first time you ask is right after the first `cout << "..."` line. The second time is in the while loop condition: `while (cin >> value)`. That second time is unnecessary, and such an unusual construct, that I missed it all the way until I ran it in the debugger :)
2. By rearranging the code, you could avoid having to duplicate the output of the question. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637598/code-not-working/18638519#18638519) for an example of such code structure. Look for `do() ... while (not ok)`.
3. Normally you can never reach an end-of-file on a standard input stream. The only time it's reached is when the other end (the terminal) has closed the "pipe". This means that once you hit end-of-file, you can never read anything else - your program is mute at this point and won't ever get any more input. That's probably *not* what you want. The suggestion to use a sentinel value (say "type -1 to finish") makes more sense.

Comment: I think reading from `cin` causes `cout` to be flushed, actually. Otherwise he would not see the question first time either. Not 100% sure, please verify before possibly editing the answer...

Comment: Also, waiting for EOF on standard input is perfectly normal, using a sentinel value is redundant. User does not expect it to be error, if they send EOF to end input (ctrl-d on Unix-style shells, crtl-z on CP/M, MS-DOS, Windows style shells.

Comment: Yeah, but the presumption is that there will be more interaction, right? Once you hit Ctrl-Z, you're done, isn't it so?

Comment: Yes, EOF is end of input. If there is menu structure or something, then some input needs to mean "return to menu", and so on. I'd still avoid sentinel values, and istead use a non-numeric command.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are doing `cin>>value` twice in the loop, but using `value` only once.
2. You need to check for both `cin.eof()` (probably `cin.bad()` too) and `cin.fail()`, separately. Note that `cin.eof()` may imply `cin.fail()` so you need to check for `eof` first, or for `fail && ! eof`, or something.